# select all the text from input field by double clicking on it

Tags: qt, qml

How can I allow the User to automatically select all the content of the text input field by double clicking on it?

```
    SpinBox {
        id: spinQQ
        from: -100 * 100
        value: 110
        to: 100 * 100
        stepSize: 10
        editable: true
        x: 40
        y: 50

        property int decimals: 2
        property real realValue: value / 100

        validator: DoubleValidator {
            bottom: Math.min(spinQQ.from, spinQQ.to)
            top: Math.max(spinQQ.from, spinQQ.to)
        }

        textFromValue: function(value, locale) {
            return Number(value / 100).toLocaleString(locale, 'f', spinQQ.decimals)
        }

        valueFromText: function(text, locale) {
            return Number.fromLocaleString(locale, text) * 100
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a MouseArea?

Comment: @JarMan I've looked up the documentation for MouseArea and there is a DoubleClick event but I dont know how to access the text input field within spinbox. This is also my first program that Im using PySide. Can you give me some guidance? Also I dont have any experience with javascript is there a way to select all the text?